# repeat google search with omitted results in shell script

Tags: shell-script, google

I have a shell script that pulls google results for a specific search query. For some search terms google only returns a few results and says "In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 10 already displayed.
If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included." Is there a way I can get the script to return the result set I get when i click the "repeat the search with the omitted results included"? (in other words can i configure the shell script to find that option and click it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the search query parameter `filter=0` to run the search with the omitted results included.

Comment: Sorry, i am still new to shell scripting. Where could i add this parameter. I call a python script that does the actual google search. Would i have to set this there?

Comment: @SteveK without seeing your code it's impossible to advise you where to add this parameter. You said you had a shell script, so I envisaged you using `wget` or `curl`; I can't help you with Python.